# Dimensions of matrix do not match after applying the derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace, differential

I am trying to find the derivative of the following function 
$F(X)=trace(AX^TB)$ With A is (p,p) matrix ,X a (d,p) matrix and B a (d,n) matrix
I am really confused because when I compute the derivative I got 
$BA$ which is mathematically impossible because B is a (d,n) matrix and A is (p,p) matrix

I will really appreciate if someone can help me to figure this problem out

Thanks

Comment: In order for the cyclic property of the trace to be satisfied, you must set $n=p$; in other words the shape of $AX^TB$ must be square.  Once you do that $BA$ is possible.

Comment: Thanks greg I understand now